# determine roles that have access to an item in Sitecore - in code

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

**Sitecore 6.5** system:
In code, is there a way to determine which roles have access to a specific item?

I have an extranet set up, some items are "protected" - meaning the anonymous account has had the inheritance broken, and certain roles have been granted read access.  I already have a custom pipeline built, so I can determine when user attempts to view a protected item, but I need to determine what role(s) has access to view the item so I can direct them appropriately.

Thanks,
Thad

**edit:**

Here is the relevant code - there may be a better way of doing this (I inherited the system & code), but I am attempting to utilize what was already in place. The problem with the code below is that Sitecore.Context.Item is null when the user doesn't have permission.

```cs
public class NotFoundProcessor : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PermissionDenied)
        {
            //determine what role would give the user access
            foreach(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role role in Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles())
            {
                bool roleCanRead = Sitecore.Context.Item.Security.CanRead(role);

                //... do stuff here

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the top of my head, you can check all the roles if they have `read` access to chosen item:

```cs
foreach (Role role in RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles())
{
  bool roleCanRead = item.Security.CanRead(role);
}
```

---

**EDIT** after code sample provided:

You need to try to resolve the item in the same way as `ItemResolver` does but wrapped it with `SecurityDisabler` and without setting it to `Sitecore Context` afterwards. This will allow you to find the requested item despite the fact the user doesn't have access to it:

```cs
public class NotFoundProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PermissionDenied)
        {
            Item item = GetItemUsingSecurityDisabler(args);

            //determine what role would give the user access
            foreach(Role role in RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles())
            {
                bool roleCanRead = item.Security.CanRead(role);

                //... do stuff here

            }
        }
    }
}

private Item GetItemUsingSecurityDisabler(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        string path = MainUtil.DecodeName(args.Url.ItemPath);
        Item item = args.GetItem(path);
        if (item == null)
        {
            path = args.Url.ItemPath;
            item = args.GetItem(path);
        }
        if (item == null)
        {
            path = args.LocalPath;
            item = args.GetItem(path);
        }
        if (item == null)
        {
            path = MainUtil.DecodeName(args.LocalPath);
            item = args.GetItem(path);
        }
        SiteContext site = Sitecore.Context.Site;

        string rootPath = site != null ? site.RootPath : string.Empty;

        if (item == null)
        {
            path = FileUtil.MakePath(rootPath, args.LocalPath, '/');
            item = args.GetItem(path);
        }
        if (item == null)
        {
            path = MainUtil.DecodeName(FileUtil.MakePath(rootPath, args.LocalPath, '/'));
            item = args.GetItem(path);
        }

        // I've ommited resolving item using DisplayName but you can add if necessary here

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @maras, I wasn't aware Security.CanRead works with roles (the context help only lists Account as the parameter). However, I'm having a problem using this method because without permission to the item, Sitecore.Context.Item is null.

Comment: Could you describe more precisely when you want to access the item? Do you have some custom pipeline processor? Could you paste some code?

Comment: I added some code above, but yes, I have a custom pipeline processor that was originally set up to better handle 404 messaging, and I'm attempting to also determine if the user does not have access (easily done) and what role(s) they need to be in to view the item (where I'm stuck).

Comment: You need to try to resolve the item in the same way as `ItemResolver` does but wrapped it with `SecurityDisabler` and without setting it to `Sitecore Context` afterwards. This will allow you to find the requested item despite the fact the user doesn't have access to it (see updated answer).